# Print values in Python list reporting ValueError

Tags: python

I have two lists :

```
a = [0,1]
b = ['a' , 'b']
```

and would like the following output:

```
0
a
1
b
```

I tried the following and it gives a `ValueError`:

```
for k,v in (a,b):
    print (k,v)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are using is not doing what you expect it to do.
What you are doing could be achieved by using the `zip` function and would look like this:

```
for k,v in zip(a,b):
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to accomplish your goal like this:

```
for i,j in zip(a, b):
    print('{}\n{}'.format(i,j))
```

gives:

```
0
a
1
b
```

Comment: thank you folks.  i also managed to get it working using the below but yours is cleaner and simpler.

<pre>

    for i in range (len (a)):
        print (a[i], b[i], sep = '\n')

</pre>

Comment: @joshrain Sure thing, happy to help  .. yes, lots of ways to get to the solution, but I agree, zip seems to be a good fit here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a print formatters, e.g.:

```
for k,v in (a,b):
    print "%s,%s" % (k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why'd you be getting a ValueError.

```
for k in a + b:
    print k
```

a + b merges the lists a and b.

Comment: AFAIK, that would merge `a` and `b` on every iteration. That's very computationally expensive!

Comment: @rsegal: That will concatenate them and then iterate over the result.

Comment: Really? I thought that was in the "len() in `for` loops" gaffe class. Does Python do it in a smarter fashion?